# Django i18n + template include tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-i18n

I need to render a translated testimonial and I use an include block for the testimonial code like so:

```
{% include "includes/blog/testimonial.html" with text="This is the best product I've ever used!" name="Tim Z" description="Store Manager" %}
```

How would I use `blocktrans` together with the `include` tag to render the translated include tag?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to translate the text you provide to an "include" tag. If this is correct just translate it beforehand and save the result to a variable:

```
{% trans "This is the best product I've ever used!" as text %}
{% trans "Store Manager" as description %}
{% include "includes/blog/testimonial.html" with text=text name="Tim Z" description=description %}
```

Comment: Perfect, I'll try this out now and let you know.

Comment: BTW, included templates have access to the main context, so in this case you could just write `{% include "includes/blog/testimonial.html" with name="Tim Z" %}`, but I wanted to illustrate a bigger point.